# Emacs in place filename / path insertion

Tags: emacs

I am looking for a way to insert a filename/path inline while editing.  Something like an inline ido-style file selection would be perfect.  Is there anything like that out there?

Comment: i wrote something that works, but it is pretty medieval and simple: http://pastebin.com/tVHvM8st interested in a better solution still.

Comment: Do yu want to insert the *current* file's absolue path name, or any, with completion?

Comment: any with completion, as the paste does.  something a little fancier would be nice, maybe inline not using the mini-buffer

Comment: okay, you're going to want my second solution, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always use `comint-dynamic-complete-filename` for this. This does not seem to be loaded by default, but provided by `comint-mode`. Thus you could put something like

```
(autoload 'comint-dynamic-complete-filename "comint" nil t)
(global-set-key "\M-]" 'comint-dynamic-complete-filename)
```

in your `~/.emacs` or the like. Use your own prefered keybinding of course.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if you want to just insert the current file name at point, then

```
 (insert (expand-file-name (buffer-file-name)))
```

should do it.

If you want to be able to find a file at any path, then you'll want to replicate some of the code in `find-file-noselect` in `files.el` at about line 1714 .

In either case, if you want to bind this a a function, you'll probably want

```
 (defun insert-file-name-at-point ()
    (interactive) .... )
```

Comment: i am using emacs 24, and and find-file-noselect starts on 1768, what bit of it are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun insert-file-name (file &optional relativep)
  "Read file name and insert it at point.
With a prefix argument, insert only the non-directory part."
  (interactive "fFile: \nP")
  (when relativep (setq file  (file-name-nondirectory file)))
  (insert file))
```